# Listing Code Snippet goes under page numbering

Tags: floats, listings, page-breaking, minted

[image]

```
\begin{listing}[p]
\centering
\inputminted[linenos, frame=lines, firstline=46, lastline=93]{python}{Codes/MyCode.py}
\caption{Part 1 Of Feature Extraction Python Code}
\label{listing:Feat}
\end{listing}
```

I am using this piece of code for python input code snippet and I'm having a trouble since the code pard isn't complete and it goes under the page number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `listing` environment is a float, and cannot break across pages. An alternative is to *not* use it, and use `\captionof{listing}{...\label{..}}` instead of the normal `\caption`. This requires the `caption` package.

You have to be a bit careful though, that the caption alone doesn't end up on the top of the page after the code block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoflistings
\vspace*{14cm} % just for example
\inputminted[linenos, frame=lines]{python}{mpltest.py}
\captionof{listing}{Part 1 Of Feature Extraction Python Code\label{listing:Feat}}
\end{document}
```